# Kibana - Setting the JSON input to get the latest

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to render a bar chart in kibana using the data in elasticsearch.
I have two documents in my elasticsearch.

```
Document1
{
    "Name": "BDV301",
    "CheckName": "ADAccountPrivileges",
    "CompletedDate": "2015-12-15T16:05:35.607Z"
}

Document2
{
    "Name": "BDV301",
    "CheckName": "ADAccountPrivileges",
    "CompletedDate": "2014-12-15T16:05:35.607Z"
}
```

In the kibana bar chart, I always want to show the latest document(in terms of the CompletedDate field)

[image]

Can I do it using the JSON Input field?
I tried adding the json script

```
{
  "filter" : {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "CompletedDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

to get the latest document in terms of the CompletedDate, but still I get the count as 2. Strangely, I don't see my JSON input in the Elasticsearch request body in Kibana.
This is what I see in the Elasticsearch request body.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "analyze_wildcard": true,
          "query": "*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "CompletedDate": {
                  "gte": 1292433048436,
                  "lte": 1450199448436,
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CheckName",
        "size": 5,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Why is my JSON input script not appearing in the Elasticsearch request body?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the latest value of a field, you can use a terms aggregation + order by timestamp. Of course, a bar chart to do this doesn't make a lot of sense, because you will only have a bar chart with one element.

In my opinion, using a table to get the latest value makes more sense. To do this, you will have to select this options in the left column:

[image: Aggregation form]

And this will result in a table with the wanted value and when it happened.

[image: Aggregation result]

Finally, the JSON input only allows you to put attributes to the aggregation, for example, if you want to modify the precision of the [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) you can specify the precision in this box, but it is not a field to insert any thing in the Kibana query.